# javascript collapse not working

Tags: javascript

I had an html template where I added a javascript based collapsible panel. I then divided the files into 3 parts: header, body and footer, like this:

- Header: url of a javascript file
- Body: Basic html templates
- Footer:

  var CollapsiblePanel1 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel1");

Now, why is this not working?

I have included the files with the include function in the main php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you might need to call your footer code `onload` (or, better, `ondomready`):

```
document.body.onload = function() {
  var CollapsiblePanel1 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel1");
};
```

If not, then we'll need more information to help you debug - can you link us to the code?

Comment: No it didn't worked but i made a simple and new collapse panel and its working thanks anyways..